# Unable to unlock after locking when VirtualBox is in full screen mode

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8, lock-screen

I'm running 13.10 as host, with a VirtualBox 4.2.16_Ubuntu running Windows 8.1 as guest.  I had the virtual machine in full screen mode when Ubuntu locked due to inactivity.

I tried to wake the machine and discovered the standard unlock screen, where I could move the mouse pointer but could not type any characters into the password box.

I switched terminals, logged in, and shutdown the virtual machine programatically.  However, I was still unable to type in the password box on the lock screen.

I ended up just rebooting the real (host) machine, which worked fine I guess :-/

Two questions:

1. Any idea what happened here?
2. Is there a way to resolve this without rebooting the whole computer?

Comment: you can be able to enter the password using onboard.

Comment: I was unable to click anywhere on screen.  I could see the mouse pointer, but it wasn't interacting with the lock screen at all.  I'd expect Onboard to suffer the same problem, but I'll try to replicate and see.

Comment: I have the same issue, this seems to be a regression caused by the new lockscreen. I've reported a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1312322

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem on 14.04. I usually run 2 Virtualbox VMs (Windows 8.1 and CentOS 6.5). I've been running both in full screen mode on separate workspaces and my lock screen was preventing me from unlocking my computer. I found this post, so instead of running my VMs in full screen using the Virtualbox menus, I just maximized them. It's not the same VM experience (lost a little screen real estate), but I haven't had a problem with my lock screen all morning.

FYI, it also fixed my problem where VMs would move to a different workspace after waking the screens from sleep.

Answer (score 2):

I've just experienced this issue on 14.04, locked for inactivity while the Windows 8.1 VirtualBox VM was on full-screen mode. Keyboard is not working on login screen; mouse cursor moves but cannot interact.

And just found a workaround:

- Alt+F2 to a terminal and type: unity --replace
- Hit Enter, and the keyboard is working on the lock-screen again.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues happen to me as well. What most likely happened is your host hardware replaced the ram back to the host operating system and caused a programing glitch/error in the virtual machine. You may want to reduce the amount of ram that is allocated to the the VM, that may help!

Comment: Interesting.  Unfortunately reducing the RAM much isn't really an option, since I'm trying to run Visual Studio on the guest and it tends to be pretty memory hungry.  Any idea why this would happen in full screen mode but not while windowed?

Comment: Greetings, Its a possibility that your host operating system is setting the priority of the VM higher when in full screen mode. While inside of the VM I would be careful to only use visual studio and open the task manager to close all non priority processes...like any games and such. Windows is very bloated, and it requires more ram than its linux counterparts. Windows explorer alone takes up more than enough! I would allocate at least 2-3 Gigs of dedicated ram to that OS in a VM. 4 Gigs would be even smoother. I hope your local machine has DDR3 or higher

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative if Guest account is enabled is to just login and logout from the Guest account from the top right corner menu there.

After logout from Guest account, you would be at the login screen again and be able to enter the password into the lock screen to login with Virtualbox still in full screen mode.

After you login back, you would see whatever you type while you tried to login on the unresponsive login inside the virtual box application if it is an editor :) Probably your password too!

At least it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 in Virtualbox on my Windows 7 Professional PC, and although I am not running Virtualbox in full screen mode, I sometimes get the same problem.  I happen to stumble upon an easy workaround, which may or may not work for others.  I press my scrollbar wheel, which seems to trigger some event and provides me with the password prompt window.  My keyboard then works again.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this several times today, and I realized that it is because the virtual machine still had my keyboard/mouse captured.  I had to press the "HOST key" to release them; for me, the host key is the right-CTRL key (default).

This did not always work on the first try, sometimes had to click around and mash the keyboard, then press the HOST key again.  In the end, it always worked without having to force a reboot; and if I had Notepad open in the virtual machine I could even see the keys I pressed.

- I was using seamless mode, not full screen.  Hopefully the work around will still work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was obvious. Disable the screensaver/locking of the guest machines. Really, if you have the screensaver enabled for the host, that also applies to all guest displays.

Comment: Disabling lock isn't very feasible for domain-joined VMs....

Answer (score 0):

For me ubuntu 18.04 LTS and before 16.04 LTS had the same issue *(host machine), where I would be able to unlock once I had unlocked the locker, .. the screen stays black and numlock won't respond. The only option then is either reset or force power off.